# why when I type python - -version in cmd nothing appears but an empty line?

Tags: python

I've downloaded python 3.9. However, on version checking via the command line, I do get an empty line instead of a version.

I have used the following command on cmd:

```
python --version
```

Comment: Did you try `python3 --version`?

Comment: Try `python -V` or `python --version`

Comment: Try to just type `python` in cmd

Comment: Do you maybe have a batch file somewhere called `python.bat` or `python.cmd` that is masking the executable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- `python3 --version`
- `python -V`
- just type `python` and it will give you the version and some other things:

```
Python your version and some stuff
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

type `exit()` and you'll be out

by the way, `python --version --version` gives you more detailed output

and see this: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#generic-options